# Adding grunt-connect-proxy to generator-angular gruntfile.js

Tags: javascript, yeoman-generator-angular, grunt-connect-proxy

I'm trying to add grunt-connect-proxy to my gruntfile.js in a yeoman generator-angular project (generator-angular 0.15.1) but I can't seem to get it to work since the way it's written changes and I'm inexperienced in how Grunt works.

I've read many posts about this and none are particularly up-to-date, and the gruntfile changes seemingly often in how it implements livereload middleware This makes the documentation for grunt-connect-proxy to not work in my case.

The tricky part is under livereload

This is how it looks in generator-angular gruntfile:

```
// The actual grunt server settings
connect: {
  options: {
    port: 9000,
    // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
    hostname: 'localhost',
    livereload: 35729
  },
  proxies: [{
      context: '/api',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 8080,
      https: false,
      xforward: false
    }],
  livereload: {
    options: {
      open: true,

      // --- how the code looks like before I do anything

      middleware: function (connect) {
        return [
          connect.static('.tmp'),
          connect().use('/bower_components', connect.static('./bower_components')),
          connect().use('/app/styles', connect.static('./app/styles')),
          connect.static(appConfig.app)
        ];
      }
    }
  },
  ...
```

When I look at the documentation it looks like this:

```
    livereload: {
        options: {
            middleware: function (connect, options) {
                if (!Array.isArray(options.base)) {
                    options.base = [options.base];
                }

                // Setup the proxy
                var middlewares = [require('grunt-connect-proxy/lib/utils').proxyRequest];

                // Serve static files.
                options.base.forEach(function(base) {
                    middlewares.push(connect.static(base));
                });

                // Make directory browse-able.
                var directory = options.directory || options.base[options.base.length - 1];
                middlewares.push(connect.directory(directory));

                return middlewares;
            }
        }
    }
```

Can someone help me translate the documentation to the new way of writing the middleware part?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I got some help and this is how it was solved:

```
  livereload: {
    options: {
      open: true,
      middleware: function(connect) {
        var middlewares = [require('grunt-connect-proxy/lib/utils').proxyRequest];
        return middlewares.concat(
          connect.static('.tmp'),
          connect().use('/bower_components', connect.static('./bower_components')),
          connect().use('/app/styles', connect.static('./app/styles')),
          connect.static(appConfig.app)
        );
      }
    }
  }
```

Hope this helps someone else too.

Comment: Were you able to get this to work for `grunt serve:dist` ??