# Grunt Connect Proxy: 404 Not Found

Tags: angularjs, proxy, gruntjs, grunt-connect-proxy

I'm using [grunt-connect-proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-connect-proxy) "^0.2.0" to proxy to an api from my angularjs application. The project was started with yeoman angular-generator.

I've followed the instructions [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-connect-proxy) but when the proxy is used, I get:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:9000/api/users
```

**My Proxy Configuration:**

```
 connect: {
  options: {
    port: 9000,
    // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
    hostname: 'localhost',
    livereload: 35729
  },
  proxies: [{
    context: '/api', // the context of the data service
    host: 'localhost', // wherever the data service is running
    port: 8080, // the port that the data service is running on
    https: false,
    xforward: false
  }],
```

**My Middleware:**

```
livereload: {
    options: {
      open: true,
      base: '',
      middleware: function (connect, options) {
        var middlewares = [];

        middlewares.push(require('grunt-connect-proxy/lib/utils').proxyRequest);

        middlewares.push(connect.static('.tmp'));
        middlewares.push(connect.static('test'));
        middlewares.push(connect().use(
            '/bower_components',
            connect.static('./bower_components')
          ));
        middlewares.push(connect.static(appConfig.app));

        return middlewares;
      }
    }
  },
```

**My Serve Task**

```
grunt.registerTask('serve', 'Compile then start a connect web server', function (target) {
  if (target === 'dist') {
    return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
  }

  grunt.task.run([
    'clean:server',
    'wiredep',
    'concurrent:server',
    'autoprefixer:server',
    'configureProxies:server',
    'connect:livereload',
    'watch'
  ]);
});
```

**EDIT**
localhost:8080/users returns a 403 currently via Postman, so the API is running.

Comment: Did you try with server: { } before options?

Comment: Take a look at this question.. Maybe it will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34321143/adding-grunt-connect-proxy-to-generator-angular-gruntfile-js

Answer (score 0):

not directly answering your question but providing a solution (since noone else has answered) ... have you tried the npm module connect-modrewrite

this does exactly what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue i resolve this way and its work for me. Look into my code below:-

```
connect: { 
            server: { 
                options: { 
                    keepalive: true, 
                    port: 8001, 
                    protocol: 'http', 
                    hostname: '*', 
                    directory: 'dist', 
                    open: { 
                        target: 'http://localhost:8001/myDemo.html', 

                    },
                        middleware: function(connect, options, middlewares) {

                                middlewares.unshift(function(req, res, next) {
                                    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
                                    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
                                    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
                                    **if (req.method.toUpperCase() == 'POST') req.method='GET';**
                                    return next();
                                });

                                return middlewares;
                        }

                } 
            } 
        },
```

see the star marked line ie if (req.method.toUpperCase() == 'POST') req.method='GET'; i done this trick and its worked for me. This aricle also helps to me https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect#middleware